# Irfanview: Mouse control of colour correction sliders

Tags: mouse, irfanview

I'm using

- Irfanview 4.66 64 bit on
- Windows 11 (10.022621.3296) with
- A Microsoft corded optical mouse.

but this question probably applies to many other earlier versions of Irfanview and Windows and  mouse, based on my prior experience.

**Question**: How do I achieve the mouse and slider experience described in "*What I want*" below.

**"What I've got":**

When carrying out colour corrections (Shift-G) the user is presented with a number of sliders (R G B Saturation, Gamma, Contrast ...).

These may be controlled by keyboard

- Shortcut key or TAB(s) to desired slider then cursor keys up or down or
- Tab to related numeric box

or By mouse.

In all cases mouse selection may be achieved by mouse by either

- dragging the desired pointer with mouse-left-click. or
- hovering mouse over slider at any point and use mouse wheel to move pointer up/down (right/left) - with NO click needed.

The selected slider may be altered with tabbing or shortcut key or mouse click BUT this has no effect on the hover and mouse wheel action. ie a slider need not be "selected".
eg Here Contrast is selected (note dashed line), BUT if the mouse pointer is hovered over any other sliders then they will be altered by mousewheel action regardless of the selected slider.

[image]

**What I want**

**On some systems, when I select a slider it can then be altered by mouse-wheel action regardless of where the mouse pointer is.** I find this immensely useful - far more so than any alternative.

- I usually tab rapidly between sliders - my brain is used to this and the ability to jump from eg Brightness to Saturation (6 tabs) is far quicker than using a mouse. Also, by using tab or shift tab with the left hand and mouse wheel (no pointer movement needed) adjustments can be extremely rapid.

However, this feature does not work on some other systems. I have been unable to determine a pattern or find if there is some method of changing this. I have explored Irfanview settings extensively, and Windows mouse control features. I'm aware that I may be able to achieve the desired result using a third party program, but if the capability can be achieved without extra software that would be desirable.

That said, suggestions of ways to achieve this "by other means" would be welcome. These would preferably but not necessarily be free.

Answer (score 1):

Allen Mulvey on PICList solved my problem.
There is an obscure (to me at least) Windows setting that changes the system behaviour.

Allen said -

- Windows has a mouse setting "scroll inactive windows"
  Go to Settings/Bluetooth & Devices/Mouse

It worked.

BUT - it was ON
Turning it OFF achieves what I want.
Which is the opposite of what I may have expected.

Presumably this setting is semi-randomly disabled or enabled in various systems, for reasons unknown to me, and accounts for the variable behaviour that I have encountered over the years.

ie that sort of translates as
"Do not scroll inactive windows when hovering over them".
Which seems to translate to "Scroll selected sliders whether or not hovering over them" - !!! :-)

Regardless of the logic, it works.

Many thanks !